# Adding tables to sql server result in Domain\user.name.tablename

Tags: sql-server-2005

Our app uses migratordotnet to modify the backing SQL Server 2005 database.  This works great 99% of the time but we are running into an issue.  We have a client that is using and Active Directory group for sql server login and when new tables are added it creates them as Domain\login.table_name.  What permissions are needed to be given to the AD group to add the tables as dbo.table_name?  This does not happen in with all of our clients with similar configurations so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the default schema for that login / group is set to dbo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the default schema for a group?  I was unable to do that using the management studio.  I am trying a solution now that specifies the schema "dbo.table_name"